# Babel : turn off import directives transpilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to use the babel transpiler to use ES6 in a project, but i'm struggling with something quite unusual : I'm working with an enhanced ES5 js codebase that contains imports and export directives.

Here is an example :

```
import Widget from 'component:component-widget';

//ES5 code here

export default "something"
```

I would like to keep those imports, but transpile the rest of detected ES6 features.

I did not find a way to do it so far... :/

Do you know if something like that could be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't include module transpilation if you don't need it. Have a look at the documentation for how to configure Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/ .

Comment: Ok I got it. I was using the "env" preset, but I did not find a way to use this preset without module transpilation, so I configured my babelrc with hand picked plugins. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`babel-preset-env` has the option [`modules`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env#modules). Setting it to `false` disables transformation of modules (import/export etc.).

The `.babelrc` would look like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: What about Babel 7?

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin Should work on Babel 7 too. Just tried and it worked for me.